# Adding GIT to copy of the source code

Tags: git

On legacy project with  2 environments **prod** and **dev**.
We recently added git on **prod** and pushed all the changes in the master branch, and can now support this server better.

However I have trouble initiating the git tracking on our **dev** server,
there code base there is a bit different and I can not just clone it fresh...

What are the proper steps to add git repository tracking, to existing code, similar to the master branch ?

I tried:

```
git init
git origin add remote ...
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

But now all my local files are shown as locally deleted.

`git checkout master`  shows conflict on all files
`git pull` says all is up to date

Comment: What are you trying to do? using one repo and add the second one to it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Clone your new repo to a stand-alone server
2. In cloned repo create a new branch `develop`
3. Rsync your codebase from your dev server into this repo
4. Commit 'develop' branch and push to remote.
5. Setup your dev server to track `develop` branch
6. Merge `develop` branch into `master`.  This will be a new `prod` codebase.

Disclamer.  This is not an endorsement of a proper release process, just the answer to OP problem